# 'hardwareBackPress' listener not removed on 'blur' event in react native android

Tags: android, react-native

```
useEffect(() => {
        const backAction = () => {
            Alert.alert("Hold on!", "Are you sure you want to exit the app?", [
                {
                    text: "Cancel",
                    onPress: () => null,
                    style: "cancel"
                },
                { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
            ]);
            return true;
        };

        const backHandler = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);
        });

        const unsubscribeblur = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', _ => {
                console.log('Event listener removed!');
            });
        });

        // Return the function to unsubscribe from the event so it gets removed on unmount

        return () => {
            backHandler.remove();
            unsubscribeblur.remove();
        }
}, [navigation]);
```

Even after adding a 'blur' listener, which removes the 'hardwareBackPress' listener, Alert still pops up on other screens.

Comment: What do you want to achieve overall?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't remove the backAction function when blur.

```
const unsubscribeblur = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',  backAction)       });
```